# Get parameters from routeProvider in element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element directive and I want to know if I can get parameters from routeProvider to render my template and set it up in my controller.

```
adminDash.directive('hospitals', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'www/partials/admin/hospitals.html',
        controller: 'AdminHospitalsController',
        controllerAs: 'hospitalsCtrl',
    };
});
```

How can I get any parameters in my element directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate the scope of the directive, like this:

```
adminDash.directive('hospitals', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'www/partials/admin/hospitals.html',
        controller: 'AdminHospitalsController',
        controllerAs: 'hospitalsCtrl',
        scope: {
            paramValue: '&',
            paramVariable: '=',
        },
    };
});
```

check this to understand better https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it: both involve using [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) service that allows you to retrieve current set of route parameters.

Given that you have an url: `http://example.com/#/hospitals/foobar` and a route `/hospitals/:hospital/` configured in your `$routeProvider`, you can:

1.Inject $routeParams into your directive:

```
adminDash.directive('hospitals', function($routeParams) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'www/partials/admin/hospitals.html',
        controller: 'AdminHospitalsController',
        controllerAs: 'hospitalsCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.hospital = $routeParams.hospital;
        }
    };
});
```

2.Inject $routeParams into `AdminHospitalsController`

```
adminDash.controller('AdminHospitalsController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.hospital = $routeParams.hospital;
}
```

Both method will result in having `hospital=foobar` in your directive's scope;